# How to fix the "ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[main,5,main]" in Google cloud VMs

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a cluster of VM instances in Google cloud. There are 4 worker nodes and 1 master node.
Things that I have configured:

1. Created "sparkuser" and given sudo privileges
2. Installed same version of Java JDK and JRE in all machines and configured the path.
3. Installed same version of Scala and sparks.
4. Hosts file and host name added, able to ssh between each machines.
5. Configured the "spark-env.sh" and "slaves" file in spark on each machines

However, when I try to run this bash command "start-master.sh" it starts all the VM's spark in cluster. But with the jps command I cannot see any master and workers, on checking the file in: /spark/log
The log file contains the error and I tried to solve it with various ways found in the developers' community. Unfortunately, I am still not able to solve the issue:
I am adding the log file here:

```
sparkuser@master:~$ start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out
worker4: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker4.out
worker3: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker3.out
worker2: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker2.out
worker1: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-worker1.out
sparkuser@master:~$ jps
3280 Jps
sparkuser@master:~$ cat /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out.6
cat: /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out.6: No such file or directory
sparkuser@master:~$ cat /opt/spark/logs/spark-sparkuser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-master.out.5
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host 35.216.27.9 --port 7100 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
22/09/30 07:09:21 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 3913@master
22/09/30 07:09:21 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
22/09/30 07:09:21 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
22/09/30 07:09:21 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
22/09/30 07:09:22 WARN Utils: Your hostname, master resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.178.0.3 instead (on interface ens4)
22/09/30 07:09:22 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
22/09/30 07:09:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/09/30 07:09:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sparkuser
22/09/30 07:09:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sparkuser
22/09/30 07:09:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/09/30 07:09:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/09/30 07:09:22 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(sparkuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(sparkuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7100. Attempting port 7101.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7101. Attempting port 7102.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7102. Attempting port 7103.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7103. Attempting port 7104.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7104. Attempting port 7105.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7105. Attempting port 7106.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7106. Attempting port 7107.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7107. Attempting port 7108.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7108. Attempting port 7109.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7109. Attempting port 7110.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7110. Attempting port 7111.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7111. Attempting port 7112.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7112. Attempting port 7113.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7113. Attempting port 7114.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7114. Attempting port 7115.
22/09/30 07:09:23 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7115. Attempting port 7116.
22/09/30 07:09:23 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[main,5,main]
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries (starting from 7100)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkMaster' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22/09/30 07:09:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Answer (score 1):

On spark/conf/spark-env.sh file add these following:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
export SPARK_WOKER_DIR=/opt/spark/conf/slaves "user-case based path"
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs
```

Along with that please ensure that you are able to SSH between all machines.
If you run scp among the machines and it runs without any error then the cluster will start. If SSH is working, but SCP is not working then remove the pub_keys and start over the key exchange process.
I hope this works.
It worked for me.